# How to change GUI language in Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, language, gui, exchange

A new guy at work moved in from Denmark, which means that he initially logged in to our Outlook Web Access 2007 from a computer with Danish Windows.
As a result, all the objects in the tree-view in Outlook are now in Danish.
For example, "Inbox" is called "Indbakke".
This prevails, even though he has now logged in locally on his assigned work computer which has English Windows.
We're running Exchange 2003, if that matters.

How do you change the language of the names of the objects in Outlook 2007?

The "Microsoft Office 2007 Language Settings" tool doesn't do this, and I couldn't find anything relevant to this by googling either.
In Exchange System Manager there are the "Details Templates" which define these things in different languages, but over on his mailbox there was no configuration option to change which language to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think that [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310757.aspx) is applicable to Exchange 2007 as well. Or you can instruct the user to change their language in the OWA "Options" pane.

Comment: Unfortunately not. :(
It's a PowerShell-setting, it's not available in Exchange 2003.

The only language-setting that's available in the OWA Options pane is for spelling.
Also, this is not specific to OWA, it's in Outlook 2007 too.

Comment: Try `Outlook.exe /ResetFolderNames` as per [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/188856).

Comment: Yes, executing "Outlook.exe /resetfoldernames" solved the problem! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

"Outlook.exe /ResetFolderNames"

I had to find the Outlook.exe directory and then BOOM. The command worked for me! ;)